Magento2: How to make phone number field look like this without using inputMask js libray?
if i enter 3064758254
the inputMask js library automatically converts it into like this (306)475-8254
How can I do this without inputMask library?


You can do this using javascript, fiddle link is
https://jsfiddle.net/tr59bocw/1/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Phone Number Formatter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="phone-input">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone-input" name="phone" maxlength="14" placeholder="(306)475-8254">
    </form>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            const phoneInput = document.getElementById("phone-input");

            phoneInput.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
                let value = phoneInput.value.replace(/\D/g, ""); // Remove all non-digit characters

                if (value.length > 0) {
                    if (value.length <= 3) {
                        value = `(${value}`;
                    } else if (value.length <= 6) {
                        value = `(${value.substring(0, 3)})${value.substring(3)}`;
                    } else if (value.length <= 10) {
                        value = `(${value.substring(0, 3)})${value.substring(3, 6)}-${value.substring(6)}`;
                    } else {
                        value = `(${value.substring(0, 3)})${value.substring(3, 6)}-${value.substring(6, 10)}`;
                    }
                }

                phoneInput.value = value;
            });

            phoneInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
                if (event.key === "Backspace") {
                    let value = phoneInput.value;

                    // Remove formatting characters if at those positions
                    if (value.endsWith(") ") || value.endsWith("-")) {
                        phoneInput.value = value.slice(0, -1);
                    } else if (value.endsWith("(")) {
                        phoneInput.value = value.slice(0, -2); // Remove "( "
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


If this is the telephone field
<div class="field telephone required">
            <label for="telephone" class="label">
                <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="telephone"
                    id="telephone"
                    maxlength="13"
                    minlength="13"
                    title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?>"
                    class="input-text validate-phone-13">
            </div>

then the js code will be
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    "jquery"
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#telephone").keypress(function () {
            let x = $(this).val();
            x = x.replace(/\D+/g, '').replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1)$2-$3');
            $(this).val(x);
        });
        $("#telephone").focusout(function () {
            let x = $(this).val();
            x = x.replace(/\D+/g, '').replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1)$2-$3');
            $(this).val(x);
        });
    });
});

